# Modifying list of name-value dictionaries to one flat dict

Tags: python-3.x

When I retrieve some values from remote system using API call, I get it as json in the following format:

```
[
  {
    "name": "foo1",
    "value": "bar1"
  },
  {
    "name": "xyz",
    "value": "aaa"
  },
  {
    "name": "John",
    "value": "Doe"
  }
]
```

Later, I need to process this data several times, and I always find it much easier to have it as one simple dict:

```
{
  "foo1": "bar1",
  "xyz": "aaa",
  "John": "Doe"
}
```

I used this function to transform data:

```
def transform_data(source_data):
    result_data = {}
    for item in source_data:
        name = item['name']
        value = item['value']
        result_data[name] = value
    return result_data
```

(I am sort of a beginner in Python), My questions are:

1. Is it "normal" that I find transformed data to be more readable (and result in more readable code when I need to process it), or is it just because of my lack of knowledge/experience with the language (or maybe my specific use case)?
2. is this transformation usual - does it have some common name that I could use for naming my function?
3. Can my function be (significantly) improved in any way?

Comment: It isn't about being "normal" or "usual". If it works for you for your specific use-case, if it makes your resulting code that uses that data more readable to you, then go for it. As for naming, it can be referred to as "flattening the data" or "reverse-mapping keys and values", but nothing wrong with "transform_data".

Comment: This is not really on-topic for StackOverflow. That said, your function can be turned into a one-liner: `return {item["name"]: item["value"] for item in source_data}`.

Comment: You really have to be careful here. You can lose data without noticing if the `"name"` is not unique for every item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have mentioned, stack overflow is generally less about style guidelines and more about actual problems in code. That being said, your question still warrants an answer.

1. YES

There are two points of interest here. The first is that python is a language written for the programmer, it is completely natural to want to have data in a form that you can use.

The second (and more important) point is the following:
data types tend to have methods that work fast on them. Consider this:

Finding a value in a list of key value pairs isn't a method, but finding a value from a dict is. This is because **dicts are made for getting out values from keys quickly**. When something is easier to do with a specific data type, that is a good sign that said data type was **made to do that specific thing**.

2. Maybe?

Finding good names for your functions is a bit of an unnecessary and difficult art. I can't think of one off the top of my head, but there probably is.

3. Others have addressed this in the comment sections:

Your code can be made neater, but not to run significantly faster.